# Error al consultar datos heredando metodos

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos muchachos. Estoy elaborando un proyecto en PHP Orientado a objetos con PDO, resulta que estoy haciendo las pruebas de los métodos y se me a presentado un error en la consulta por id. Procedo a explicar mi código:

Primero tengo mi clase Conexión en el cual tengo mi constructor con la conexión y dos métodos mas:

```
<?php namespace Models;

class Conexion{
    private $con;

    public function __construct(){

        try{
            $this->con = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poo_pdo','root','');

        }catch(PDOExcepcion $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }

    //Metodo para llamar la conexion y decirle que se va a ejecutar una query
    public function consultaSimple($sql){
        $this->con->prepare($sql); 
    }

    //Metodo para retornar lo que se consulte
    public function consultaRetorno($sql){
        $datos= $this->con->prepare($sql);
        return $datos;
    }
}
?>
```

La siguiente clase es la del Estudiante. El metodo que me esta presentando problema es el que se llama view(), resulta que me esta retornando false, he impreso con var_dump y me esta mostrando false, no esta retornando nada, esta es la clase:

```
<?php namespace Models; 

class Estudiante{

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $edad;
    private $promedio;
    private $imagen;
    private $fecha;
    private $id_seccion;
    private $con;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->con = new Conexion();
    }

    public function set($atributo, $contenido){
        $this->$atributo = $contenido;
    }

    public function get($atributo){
        return $this->$atributo;
    }

    public function listar(){
        $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.nombre as nombre_seccion FROM estudiantes t1 INNER JOIN secciones t2 ON t1.id_seccion = t2.id";
        $datos=$this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
        return $datos;
    }

    public function add(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes(id,nombres,edad,promedio,img,fecha,id_seccion)
        VALUES(null,:name,:edad,:promedio,:imagen,:fecha,:id_seccion)";
        $this->con->consultaSimple($sql);
    }

    public function delete(){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM estudiantes WHERE id = :id";
        $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
    }

    public function edit(){
        $sql = "UPDATE FROM estudiantes SET nombres = :name, edad = :edad, promedio = :promedio, id_seccion = :id_seccion WHERE id = :id ";
        $this->con->consultaSimple();
    }

    public function view(){
        $sql = "SELECT nombres FROM estudiantes WHERE id = :id ";
        $datos = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
        $row = $datos->fetch();
        return $row;
    }

}
```

Como he dicho el metodo view es el que me esta dando problemas. Mediante el metodo set() le paso parametros para hacer la consulta ya que solo estoy probando. Lo hago de esta manera:

```
<?php 

require_once "Config/Autoload.php";
Config\Autoload::run();
$est = new Models\Estudiante(); //Instancio la clase
$est->set("id", 3); //Llamo al método set de la clase y le paso los parámetros que quiero consultar
$datos = $est->view();
print $datos['nombres'];
?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es consultar el estudiante con id = 3, pero como he dicho no me muestra nada en pantalla, todo en blanco y al imprimir con var_dump veo que retorna false. Necesito ayuda por favor gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te voy a dar una solución puntualmente porque va a depender de como quieras implementar las cosas.

## [Documentación de Sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Estás haciendo el `prepare` pero te faltan los `bind` y el `execute`.

**Ejemplo de `Conexion`:**

```
$this->con->prepare("SELECT nombres FROM estudiantes WHERE id = :id");
$this->con->bindParam(':id', $est->get('id'));
$this->con->execute();
```

En tu código en ningún momento especificas el valor de `:id` o cualquier otro parámetro. Para eso tenés que usar -es una opción- `bindParam()`, leé la documentación.
Por otro lado, con `prepare()` solo no alcanza, tenés que hacer un `execute()` para correr la consulta. El `fetch()` que hacés está bien, pero antes tenés que hacer el `execute()`.

Ahora, el tema es como pasás los parámetros para el `bind`. Se podrían armar funciones bastante avanzadas como las que tienen los `ORM`, pero una solución sencilla sería agregar un parámetro a `consultaSimple` y `consultaRetorno` con un `array` de `binds`.

```
/**
 * $binds por defecto es un array vacío,
 * así que podes no pasar ese parámetro.
 */
public function consultaRetorno($sql, $binds = []) {
    $datos = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($binds as $key => $val) {
        $datos->bindParam($key, $val);
    }

    return $datos->execute();
}
```

Teniendo ese método, no se que sentido tendría seguir manteniendo `consultaSimple`. Tené en cuenta que ninguna de tus `consultaSimple` se están ejecutando porque no tienen `execute()`. Yo las reemplazaría por `consultaRetorno()`, pero insisto, como no se exactamente que tenés en mente, simplemente te tiro ejemplos.

El uso sería algo así:

```
public function view() {
    $sql = "SELECT nombres FROM estudiantes WHERE id = :id";
    $params = [':id' => $this->get('id')];
    $datos = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql, $params);
    $row = $datos->fetch();

    return $row;
}
```

Cualquier cosa avisame y vamos corrigiendo lo que haga falta. Hace bastante que no uso `PDO` directamente así que pueden haber errores.

Comment: Saludos azeos. Entendi bien, y si sabia que me hacian falta los bindParam y los execute pero como dije apenas estaba probando. Pero quisiera es que consultaRetorno me sirva para cualquier método de los que tenga en la clase estudiante, solo si retornan algo. Y consultaSimple lo puse para realizar INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE Y SELECT simples. estoy viendo es que en el método consultaRetorno colocaste el bindParam pero eso solo funcionaria para el método view, quisiera que  funcione para otros métodos. Hay una manera de colocar lo que esta después del prepare en el metodo view ?

Comment: El `bindParam` que está dentro de `consultaRetorno` se ejecuta tantas veces como elementos haya dentro del `array` `binds`. Si está vacío (no pasas el parámetro), no se ejecuta nunca. Así que eso no sirve sólo para `view`, sirve para cualquiera. Por ejemplo, dentro de `edit` podrías hacer `$params = [':name' => $nombre, ':edad' => $edad]` obviamente modificando `consultaSimple`.

Comment: Ahora si creo que entendi. Supongo que se ejecuta tantas veces como elementos haya por que el foreach se encarga de eso no?

Comment: @AlejoMendoza Exactamente, el `foreach` recorre todos los elementos del `array`.

Comment: Entendido entonces. Solo me queda ir probando. Cualquier cosas puedo comentarte de nuevo azeos.?

Comment: @AlejoMendoza seguro, no hay problema.

Comment: mira el error que me esta dando Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch(). Es en el método view() en donde esta el $row = $datos->fetch();

Comment: Hacé un `var_dump($datos)` antes del `fetch` para ver que está haciendo.

Comment: devuelve true @azeos no entiendo entonces porque me esta dando ese error

Comment: he solucionado el problema. Lo que pasaba era que el return estaba asi return $datos->execute(); y primero he ejecutado y despues retorne $datos->execute, y luego hice el return $datos.

Comment: Una ultima pregunta azeos, en el metodo consultaSimple deberia modificarlo y hacerlo de la misma manera que el que retorna? Por ejemplo si quiero usar un delete en el metodo consultaSimple() como podria quedar

Comment: @AlejoMendoza `consultaSimple` quedaría exactamente igual a `consultaRetorno`. Más allá de que el `return` pueda no serte necesario, el resto es igual, por eso te decía que me parece que con un sólo método es suficiente. En `delete` sería `$this->con->consultaRetorno($sql, [':id' => $id]);` De donde obtenés el `$id` no lo se.